# How to add custom annotations to Jackson schema

Tags: json, jackson, jsonschema

I have a class, say:

```
class Data {
    public int value;
};
```

and I want to generate json schema use jackson-schema module with a valid range of the data field, like:

```
class Data {
    @JsonProperties(min = 1)
    @JsonProperties(max = 100)
    public int value;
};
```

but I search in the jackson-schema's wiki and it doesn't support this, is there some example to make the custom annotations by ourself ? thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to include custom annotations to jackson schema, but you need create several classes as below, I use this to add my custom title property:

1. Create your own `SchemaFactoryWrapper`

   ```
   public static class YourselfSchemaFactoryWrapper extends SchemaFactoryWrapper{
       private static class YourselfSchemaFactoryWrapperFactory extends WrapperFactory {
           @Override
           public SchemaFactoryWrapper getWrapper(SerializerProvider p) {
               SchemaFactoryWrapper wrapper = new YourselfSchemaFactoryWrapper();
               if (p != null) {
                   wrapper.setProvider(p);
               }
               return wrapper;
           };

           @Override
           public SchemaFactoryWrapper getWrapper(SerializerProvider p, VisitorContext rvc) {
               SchemaFactoryWrapper wrapper = new YourselfSchemaFactoryWrapper();
               if (p != null) {
                   wrapper.setProvider(p);
               }
               wrapper.setVisitorContext(rvc);
               return wrapper;
           }
       };

       public YourselfSchemaFactoryWrapper() {
           super(new YourselfSchemaFactoryWrapperFactory());
           schemaProvider = new YourselfJsonSchemaFactory();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create your own `JsonSchemaFactory`
   You can override functions of JsonSchemaFactory as you want in this class.  For this case, I just want to override string schema.

   ```
   public class YourselfJsonSchemaFactory extends JsonSchemaFactory{
       @Override
       public StringSchema stringSchema() {
           return new YourselfStringSchema();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create your own StringSchema

   ```
   public class YourselfStringSchema extends StringSchema{
       @Override
       public void enrichWithBeanProperty(BeanProperty beanProperty) {
           super.enrichWithBeanProperty(beanProperty);
           JsonPropertyTitle title = beanProperty.getAnnotation(JsonPropertyTitle.class);
           if(title != null) this.setTitle(title.value());
       }
   }
   ```
4. Then define your own annotations

   ```
   @Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @Documented
   @JacksonAnnotation
   public @interface JsonPropertyTitle
   {
       String value() default "";
   }
   ```
5. Finally, you can use this annotation to your model

   ```
   public class DataModal{
       @JsonPropertyTitle("My Custom Title")
       private str;
   }
   ```

Comment: @Dhepthi I'm using jackson-module-jsonSchema 2.8.3 and I works.  Any problems do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java validation API for this `(javax.validation.*)`.

> javax.validation.constraints.Size

```
@Size(min = 1, max = 100, message = "error message")
private String text;
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer, at least you can explain more

Comment: @Youcef edited my answer, answered from my phone not properly organised.

Answer (score 0):

One project which does that is [JJSchema](https://github.com/reinert/JJSchema). The Jackson module for JSON Schea currently does not have such fine grained control.